# tensorflow_probability subclassing JointDistributionNamed __init__ behaviour

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to create a derived class from `JointDistributionNamed` in the `tensorflow_probability` library (tensorflow v2.0.0, tensorflow_probability v0.8.0). However, the `super().__init__` function is behaving in a weird way that I don't understand. Maybe I am just using `super()` wrong, but it seems to work as I expect for other classes. Anyway here is an example:

```
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

models = {'normal': tfd.Normal(loc=0, scale=1)}
joint = tfd.JointDistributionNamed(models) # Works perfectly fine
print("joint:",joint) 

class Test(tfd.JointDistributionNamed):
    def __init__(self,name,models):
        self.myname = name
        self.models = models
        super().__init__(models) #(1) Works
        #super().__init__(self.models) #(2) Doesn't work

t = Test('hello',models)
print("t:", t)
```

The behavior when giving `models` to `super().__init__` is not the same whether I just pass `models` in or I first assign it to `self.models`. Why? In the latter case I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_jointdistnamed.py", line 18, in <module>
    t = Test('hello',models)
  File "</home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-244>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/distribution.py", line 276, in wrapped_init
    default_init(self_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "test_jointdistnamed.py", line 16, in __init__
    super().__init__(self.models) #doesn't work
  File "</home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-138>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/distribution.py", line 276, in wrapped_init
    default_init(self_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_named.py", line 170, in __init__
    model, validate_args, name or 'JointDistributionNamed')
  File "</home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-70>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/distribution.py", line 276, in wrapped_init
    default_init(self_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_sequential.py", line 211, in __init__
    self._model_unflatten(self._model_flatten(model))
  File "/home/farmer/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/joint_distribution_named.py", line 186, in _model_unflatten
    return type(self.model)(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normal'
```

It's like it is trying to unpack the `models` dict somewhere inside the class hierarchy for some reason. But why the heck would that be different depending on whether I first assign to `self`? Aren't I passing a reference to exactly the same dictionary either way? What is different? Is this a bizarre bug or am I doing something wrong somehow? The exact same thing seems to work just fine if I make up my own simple custom class rather than `JointDistributionNamed`.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be something to do with `tf.Module` dependency tracking wrapper objects for fields.
What is `type(self.models)`? If you change to `self._models = self._no_dependency(models)` does it work?